# Dual boot: several Windows 7 loading entries in GRUB2 - should I delete any?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, uefi

The system is Acer Extensa 2510G, and there's only one HDD.

This is how the GRUB2 menu looks:

[image]

Output of sudo update-grub2:

[image]

The scripts themselves:

Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi:

```
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root F27A-20E4
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Windows Boot UEFI loader:

```
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root F27A-20E4
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
```

Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1):

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  F27A-20E4
else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F27A-20E4
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

So can I safely delete any of these entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, code samples should be entered with four spaces preceding each line. Using carats (`>`) at the start of the line is used for quoting content, and does *not* preserve critical code formatting. I've fixed your question so it's properly formatted. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for more on formatting features on this site.

As to your question, there are two answers. The first is empirical: Try each option from your GRUB menu and remove any that does not work. If two or more work, you can choose which to delete randomly.

The second answer is more theoretical: The `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` file is the official location of the Windows boot loader, whereas `/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` is the fallback/default EFI boot loader. In practice they may be the same binaries under two names, but another OS might overwrite the latter. The Windows boot loader *shouldn't* be replaced or erased, but buggy tools and hackish workarounds for buggy EFIs may dictate otherwise. The third GRUB configuration that you quote is simply a more elaborate version of the first one. Personally, I'd keep it simple if simple works.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and clarification. All 3 Windows entries were equally working but I didn't want my GRUB menu cluttered with unnecessary entries. I see the reason to keep /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi but I have deleted the 3rd entry.