# Unnecessary entries in Grub2 Boot Menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I just finished repairing Grub2 after a SSD-to-SSD clone. Now when I boot up I see the Grub boot menu, but I see several entries I hadn't seen before the clone. I've tried booting `Ubuntu` and `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)` and both of them boot up successfully.

The entries I don't recognize are `Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi` and `EFI/*`.

I run Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10 which are mostly what I'm interested in, but maybe there is some importance to the EFI options?

Also, I don't ever recall seeing the `System Setup` entry.

Does anyone recognize these and have an opinion as to whether I should keep all of these entries or remove them? Eventually I want Windows to be the default. I suspect `System Setup` may be the Windows or Dell Recovery Partition, but I haven't ran it yet so I don't know.

I just want to clean up the menu and get rid of unneeded entries as well as set Grub to default to Windows. Also, where are these boot options configured?

Any help is appreciated. Thx.

[image: Screenshot of Grub menu on PC startup]

Comment: This can be helpful http://askubuntu.com/questions/609970/dual-boot-several-windows-7-loading-entries-in-grub2-should-i-delete-any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal; it's happened to me on many UEFI computers. The `boot*.efi` entries and the `Windows Boot UEFI Loader` one should all boot Windows. `MokManager.efi` is for managing Secure Boot keys. You probably won't ever use it, but you probably want to keep it around just in case you end up needing it. The `System setup` entry actually boots into BIOS setup, not a recovery partition.

[Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) is a good program to remove the duplicate Windows entries. You can install it from its PPA and run it with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
grub-customizer
```

Note that "removing" an entry only hides it; you can restore it later if you, for whatever reason, need it back.

To set Windows as the default OS, just move its entry to the top; it will boot after (by default) 10 seconds, unless you select a different OS.

Comment: Nice answer. This helps me out a lot. Linux/Ubuntu is not my native OS. I use it for sure, but am stumped on some of these configuration tasks. Thanks!